# No sound via HDMI on 13.04

Tags: sound, 13.04, hdmi

I have upgraded to 13.04 and now I have no sound. I use an `HDMI lead` to connect my PC to the TV, but now I don't have that as an option to choose from.

I just have two output options:

1. Digital
2. Analogue

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

it's a known bug. Review & subscribe to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1169984
The bug report has workarounds while we wait for a fix to be committed. The workaround which works for everyone is to use the mainline 3.8 kernel as described in the report.

Answer (score 0):

Radeon HDMI Linux Audio Might Be Restored Soon:

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM1MTM

Answer (score 0):

Please try latest updated package (20130510) provided on :https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/+packages

I installed it and works perfectly fine after restart.

Cheers,
Dnyandeep